# How to get the MouseEvent coordinates for an element that has CSS3 Transform?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I want to detect **where** a `MouseEvent` has occurred, in **coordinates relative to the clicked element**. Why? Because I want to add an absolutely positioned child element at the clicked location.

I know how to detect it when no CSS3 transformations exist (see description below). However, when I add a CSS3 Transform, then my algorithm breaks, and I don't know how to fix it.

I'm not using any JavaScript library, and I want to understand how things work in plain JavaScript. So, please, don't answer with "just use jQuery".

By the way, I want a solution that works for all MouseEvents, not just "click". Not that it matters, because I believe all mouse events share the same properties, thus the same solution should work for all of them.

---

### Background information

According to [DOM Level 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mouseevents), a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/UIEvent/MouseEvent) has few properties related to getting the event coordinates:

- `screenX` and `screenY` return the screen coordinates (the origin is the top-left corner of user's monitor)
- `clientX` and `clientY` return the coordinates relative the document viewport.

Thus, in order to find the position of the `MouseEvent` relative to the clicked element content, I must do this math:

```
ev.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left - this.clientLeft + this.scrollLeft
```

- `ev.clientX` is the coordinate relative to the document viewport
- `this.getBoundingClientRect().left` is the position of the element relative to the document viewport
- `this.clientLeft` is the amount of border (and scrollbar) between the element boundary and the inner coordinates
- `this.scrollLeft` is the amount of scrolling inside the element

[`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect), [`clientLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientLeft) and [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollLeft) are specified at [CSSOM View Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-element-interface).

### Experiment without CSS Transform (it works)

Confusing? [Try the following piece of JavaScript and HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/7CKyT/5/). Upon clicking, a red dot should appear exactly where the click has happened. This version is "quite simple" and works as expected.

```
function click_handler(ev) {
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var left = ev.clientX - rect.left - this.clientLeft + this.scrollLeft;
    var top = ev.clientY - rect.top - this.clientTop + this.scrollTop;

    var dot = document.createElement('div');
    dot.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute; width: 2px; height: 2px; top: '+top+'px; left: '+left+'px; background: red;');
    this.appendChild(dot);
}

document.getElementById("experiment").addEventListener('click', click_handler, false);

<div id="experiment" style="border: 5px inset #AAA; background: #CCC; height: 400px; position: relative; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="width: 900px; height: 2px;"></div> 
    <div style="height: 900px; width: 2px;"></div>
</div>
```

### Experiment adding a CSS Transform (it fails)

Now, [try adding a CSS `transform`](http://jsfiddle.net/7CKyT/6/):

```
#experiment {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    /* Note that this is a very simple transformation. */
    /* Remember to also think about more complex ones, as described below. */
}
```

The algorithm doesn't know about the transformations, and thus calculates a wrong position. What's more, the results are different between Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 12. Opera 11.50 behaves just like Chrome.

In this example, the only transformation was scaling, so I could multiply the scaling factor to calculate the correct coordinate. However, if we think about arbitrary transformations (scale, rotate, skew, translate, matrix), and even nested transformations (a transformed element inside another transformed element), then we really need a better way to calculate the coordinates.

Comment: 'please, don't answer with "just use jQuery"' - I would upvote you for that alone...

Comment: It seems to me that if you had a way to get the 3D transformation matrix that described the original transform, you would be able to get the coordinates by making them go through the same transformation right? How about `getComputedStyle(someElement).getPropertyValue('transform')`? It seems to return exactly such a matrix. Now I'm not saying matrix calculations are easy, but they are accurate and fast...

Comment: @StijndeWitt There is an official way coming up in browsers, see my answer.

Answer (score 16):

The behaviour you are experiencing is correct, and your algorithm isn't breaking. Firstly CSS3 Transforms are designed not to interfere with the box model.

To try and explain...

When you apply a CSS3 Transform on an element. the Element assumes a kind of relative positioning. In that the surrounding elements are not effected by the transformed element.

e.g. imagine three div's in a horizontal row. If you apply a scale transform to decrease the size of the centre div. The surrounding div's will not move inwards to occupy the space that was once occupied the transformed element.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/AshMokhberi/bWwkC/

So in the box model, the element does not actually change size. Only it's rendered size changes.

You also have to keep in mind that you are applying a scale Transform, so your elements "real" size is actually the same as it's original size. You are only changing it's perceived size.

To explain..

Imagine you create a div with a width of 1000px and scale it down to 1/2 the size. The internal size of the div is still 1000px, not 500px.

So the position of your dots are correct relative to the div's "real" size.

I modified your example to illustrate.

Instructions

1. Click the div and keep you mouse in the same position.
2. Find the dot in the wrong position.
3. Press Q, the div will become the correct size.
4. Move your mouse to find the dot in the correct position to where you clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/AshMokhberi/EwQLX/

So in order to make the mouse clicks co-ordinates match the visible location on the div, you need to understand that the mouse is giving back co-ordinates based on the window, and your div offsets are also based on its "real" size.

As your object size is relative to the window the only solution is to scale the offset co-ordinates by the same scale value as your div.

However this can get tricky based on where you set the Transform-origin property of your div. As that is going to effect the offsets.

See here.

http://jsfiddle.net/AshMokhberi/KmDxj/

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is a good explanation but doesn't actually answer the question. It explains very well WHY the browser behavior is correct, but doesn't answer how to get the desired behavior (considering arbitrary transformations).

Comment: I know I can scale the coordinates in my algorithm; if it was so simple I would have done that. What you may have not noticed is that it gets a lot trickier when you mix rotation, skew, translation, or an arbitrary matrix. It gets yet even trickier if we have a transformed element inside another transformed element. This is what my question is about. And I don't like the idea of re-implementing all the transformations in JavaScript.

Comment: You are right, it will get really tricky. Unfortunately There is no other way to do it unless they change the css3 transform spec. The spec for css3 transforms is still in draft, and I think you raise a good point. I would consider joining the working draft mailing list, and raising your concerns. Details here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/ it is probably worth joining the 3d transforms mailing list, as this applies to both portions of the spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/

Comment: Posted the message, as you suggested. Thank you! http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Jul/0387.html

Comment: Your welcome, looks like you are getting some positive responses. I hope they do implement the required changes, otherwise life with CSS transforms is going to get very complicated, very quickly.

Comment: Would you mind giving my answer a tick. I don't like to ask, but I did answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, but although you gave a good explanation about the issue, it doesn't actually solve the problem. I still can't get the correct coordinates (in the general case, with arbitrary transformations). Maybe this is not possible yet, and if this is the case I think this question should remain open until a solution emerges.

Comment: I thought stack overflow was about giving answers not solving problems, even if the answer is it can't be done the way you want. That is still the correct answer is it not?

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87767/accept-an-answer-obligation

Comment: never mind, it's not like I didn't answer your question correctly, it was just not the answer you wanted hear. This answer is correct at the time it was asked.

Comment: This won't be difficult to do with upcoming DOMPoint and DOMMatrix classes (part of the w3c geometry-interfaces spec). See my answer for example.

Answer (score 9):

if element is container and positioned absolute or relative,
you can place inside of it element, 
position it relative to parent and 
width = 1px, height = 1px, and move to inside of container,
and after each move use document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)  =))))

You can use binary search to make it faster.
looks terrible, but it works

http://jsfiddle.net/3VT5N/3/ - demo

Comment: another way is place 3 divs in corners of that element, than find transform matrix ... but is also works only for positioned containerable elements

Comment: Could you please try to improve your English in your answer? I could only understand it because I carefully read your demo source-code.

Comment: I modified it slightly to get a 20-40% performance increase. Before, it was taking 50-70 ms on my 3d transforms site, now it takes 30-45 ms. http://jsfiddle.net/3VT5N/49/ is the updated version. I also changed the names of properties in the returned object from left and top to x and y, and it returns pixel coordinates instead of percentages. I also took out the toString function for no good reason and added a time property to the returned object that tells you how many milliseconds the operation took. On my computer, the new example takes about 20 ms, 1/50th of a second. It used to take 40ms.

Comment: to continue the last comment, that is 1/25th of a second, 1/2 the speed. This is because the old one, it kept setting styles, creating a new element, running document.elementFromPoint, and deleting the element again only to do it over again many, many times. This instead creates the element at the beginning, and then modifies the style of the element and runs document.elementFromPoint many times, and then deletes the element at the end. So instead of creating and deleting an element many time, it just does it once.

Comment: This is great answer, it should be accepted in my humble opinion. I just needed exactly this and implemented it - worked like a charm. Sure it can have improvement in performance, but general approach is great.

Comment: @Sinisa No, this is hackish. See my answer for the official way that browsers will let us do this soon.

Comment: @trusktr You do see my comment was from 2014 :-)

Answer (score 5):

BY FAR the fastest. The accepted answer takes about 40-70 ms on my 3d transforms site, this usually takes less than 20 ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rA27K/14/)):

```
function getOffset(event,elt){
    var st=new Date().getTime();
    var iterations=0;
    //if we have webkit, then use webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode instead
    if(webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode){
        var webkitPoint=webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode(elt,new WebKitPoint(event.clientX,event.clientY));
        //if it is off-element, return null
        if(webkitPoint.x<0||webkitPoint.y<0)
            return null;
        return {
            x: webkitPoint.x,
            y: webkitPoint.y,
            time: new Date().getTime()-st
        }
    }
    //make full-size element on top of specified element
    var cover=document.createElement('div');
    //add styling
    cover.style.cssText='height:100%;width:100%;opacity:0;position:absolute;z-index:5000;';
    //and add it to the document
    elt.appendChild(cover);
    //make sure the event is in the element given
    if(document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX,event.clientY)!==cover){
        //remove the cover
        cover.parentNode.removeChild(cover);
        //we've got nothing to show, so return null
        return null;
    }
    //array of all places for rects
    var rectPlaces=['topleft','topcenter','topright','centerleft','centercenter','centerright','bottomleft','bottomcenter','bottomright'];
    //function that adds 9 rects to element
    function addChildren(elt){
        iterations++;
        //loop through all places for rects
        rectPlaces.forEach(function(curRect){
            //create the element for this rect
            var curElt=document.createElement('div');
            //add class and id
            curElt.setAttribute('class','offsetrect');
            curElt.setAttribute('id',curRect+'offset');
            //add it to element
            elt.appendChild(curElt);
        });
        //get the element form point and its styling
        var eltFromPoint=document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX,event.clientY);
        var eltFromPointStyle=getComputedStyle(eltFromPoint);
        //Either return the element smaller than 1 pixel that the event was in, or recurse until we do find it, and return the result of the recursement
        return Math.max(parseFloat(eltFromPointStyle.getPropertyValue('height')),parseFloat(eltFromPointStyle.getPropertyValue('width')))<=1?eltFromPoint:addChildren(eltFromPoint);
    }
    //this is the innermost element
    var correctElt=addChildren(cover);
    //find the element's top and left value by going through all of its parents and adding up the values, as top and left are relative to the parent but we want relative to teh wall
    for(var curElt=correctElt,correctTop=0,correctLeft=0;curElt!==cover;curElt=curElt.parentNode){
        //get the style for the current element
        var curEltStyle=getComputedStyle(curElt);
        //add the top and left for the current element to the total
        correctTop+=parseFloat(curEltStyle.getPropertyValue('top'));
        correctLeft+=parseFloat(curEltStyle.getPropertyValue('left'));
    }
    //remove all of the elements used for testing
    cover.parentNode.removeChild(cover);
    //the returned object
    var returnObj={
        x: correctLeft,
        y: correctTop,
        time: new Date().getTime()-st,
        iterations: iterations
    }
    return returnObj;
}
```

and also include the following CSS in the same page:

```
.offsetrect{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 33.333%;
    width: 33.333%;
}
#topleftoffset{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#topcenteroffset{
    top: 0;
    left: 33.333%;
}
#toprightoffset{
    top: 0;
    left: 66.666%;
}
#centerleftoffset{
    top: 33.333%;
    left: 0;
}
#centercenteroffset{
    top: 33.333%;
    left: 33.333%;
}
#centerrightoffset{
    top: 33.333%;
    left: 66.666%;
}
#bottomleftoffset{
    top: 66.666%;
    left: 0;
}
#bottomcenteroffset{
    top: 66.666%;
    left: 33.333%;
}
#bottomrightoffset{
    top: 66.666%;
    left: 66.666%;
}
```

It essentially splits the element into 9 squares, determines which one the click was in via `document.elementFromPoint`. It then splits that into 9 smaller squares, etc until it is accurate to within a pixel. I know I over-commented it. The accepted answer is several times slower than this.

EDIT: It is now even faster, and if the user is in Chrome or Safari it will use a native function designed for this instead of the 9 sectors thingy and can do it consistently in LESS THAN 2 MILLISECONDS!

Comment: I wish I could try this, but it seems `webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode` has been deleted from browsers (or just doesn't exist in Chrome). I posted an answer, can you check it out and see if it may work (once I finish the DOMMatrix/DOMPoint polyfill I can test it out, but it is theoretical at the moment). My answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43576626/454780

Comment: @trusktr `webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode` was non-standard in the first place. This code was designed to use it if possible, and fall back otherwise. It should work even without it.

Comment: Would you be able to post a fiddle or some live example?

Comment: That's freakin awesome!

Answer (score 3):

> another way is place 3 divs in corners of that element,
>   than find transform matrix ... but is also works only for positioned containerable
>   elements – 4esn0k

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dAwfF/3/

Comment: It seems your user is not registered within Stackoverflow, so that your two answers appear to be from different users. I think you should login/register, so that all your answers are correctly linked to your user.

Comment: Using 3 DIVs in corners will work for any arbitrary 2D CSS transformations. That's great. But how about 3D transformations?

Comment: yes, 3d will not work with such method, although with such method we can find position outside of element

Comment: also this method doesn't work in Firefox, becaouse of https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591718

Comment: I guess it would be possible to reconstruct a 3D transformation matrix using 4 elements instead of 3. It would be a bit more difficult, it would need to take perspective into account. Not sure if it is worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

To get the coordinates of a `MouseEvent` relative to the clicked element, use `offsetX` / `layerX`.

Have you tried using `ev.layerX` or `ev.offsetX`?

```
var offsetX = (typeof ev.offsetX == "number") ? ev.offsetX : ev.layerX || 0;
```

See also:

- [CSSOM View Module: 9 Extensions to the MouseEvent Interface](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-mouseevent-interface)
- IE 8 measures `clientX` from the element's padding edge instead of the content edge: [GTalbot MSIE 8 Browser Bugs: event.offsetX, event.offsetY as mouse coordinates inside element target's padding-box](http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/Opera11Bugs/Opera7BugOffsetXY.html)
- [MSDN: offsetX Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534305.aspx)

Comment: I guess you missed the part that I talk about TRANSFORMED elements (using 2D or 3D CSS transformations)

Comment: No, I read that. I tried this approach, using transforms, just before posting, and it works in the few browsers I have here. If you go to: http://songthaimassage.com/massage/ and try `document.images[1].onclick = function(ev) {
var offsetX = (typeof ev.offsetX == "number") ? ev.offsetX : ev.layerX || 0;
console.log(offsetX);
};` Then click on the left edge of the first gallery image, then, after it zooms, click the near the left edge (you'll have to move your mouse), you should see a result near 0.

Comment: This is fantastic and helped me with an issue I was having due to 3d transforms where pageX and clientX were requiring significant other math to get them to be right! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Garrett, it works like a charm! Helped me a lot. And so less code, amazing!

Comment: Just found out that that solution is not working on all Android 4.x devices. (tested with 4.2.2 and 4.1.1, both not working)

Comment: It seems that this was originally an MSIE-only property that has been added to a draft specification by W3C.  How widely supported is this, given that there is no official published specification of it?

Comment: @Garrett This doesn't work. Maybe the transforms you tried were too simple. Make complex 3D scene involving multiple levels of nest elements with rotation, scale, skew, translation, then you'll see that those values are on screen pixel space, not on element space.

Comment: I also posted an answer with what will be the official way to do it in all browsers, using DOMMatrix and DOMPoint (see w3c geometry-interfaces) spec.

Answer (score 3):

Also, for Webkit [webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/DOMWindowAdditionsReference/DOMWindowAdditions/DOMWindowAdditions.html) method can be used:

```
var div = document.createElement('div'), scale, point;
div.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;left:-1000px;top:-1000px';
document.body.appendChild(div);
scale = webkitConvertPointFromNodeToPage(div, new WebKitPoint(0, 0));
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
scale.x = -scale.x / 1000;
scale.y = -scale.y / 1000;
point = webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode(element, new WebKitPoint(event.pageX * scale.x, event.pageY * scale.y));
point.x = point.x / scale.x;
point.y = point.y / scale.x;
```

Comment: Do you have any link to the documentation of this function?

Comment: This function is deprecated. So lets write tons of code to detect local coordinate of a mouse or touch event on a 3d rotated element ie: canvas for : looking up if that point is transparent? Or painting something at right there... Omg. Stupid stupid stupid.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work really well for me

```
var elementNewXPosition = (event.offsetX != null) ? event.offsetX : event.originalEvent.layerX;
var elementNewYPosition = (event.offsetY != null) ? event.offsetY : event.originalEvent.layerY;
```

Comment: This answer is the same as @Garrett's earlier answer, thus adds nothing useful to this question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: my answer is untested, WIP, I will update when I get it working.**

I'm implementing a polyfill of the [geomtetry-interfaces](https://github.com/trusktr/geometry-interfaces/). The `DOMPoint.matrixTransform` method I will make next, which means we should be able to write something like the following in order to map a click coordinate onto a transformed (possiblly nested) DOM element:

```
// target is the element nested somewhere inside the scene.
function multiply(target) {
    let result = new DOMMatrix;

    while (target && /* insert your criteria for knowing when you arrive at the root node of the 3D scene*/) {
        const m = new DOMMatrix(target.style.transform)
        result.preMultiplySelf(m) // see w3c DOMMatrix (geometry-interfaces)
        target = target.parentNode
    }

    return result
}

// inside click handler
// traverse from nested node to root node and multiply on the way
const matrix = multiply(node)
const relativePoint = DOMPoint(clickX, clickY, 0, 800).matrixTransform(matrix)
```

`relativePoint` will be the point relative to the element's surface that you clicked on.

A w3c DOMMatrix can be constructed with a CSS transform string argument, which makes it super easy to use in JavaScript.

Unfortunately, this isn't working yet (only Firefox has a geometry-interfaces implementation, and my polyfill does not yet accept a CSS transform string). See: https://github.com/trusktr/geometry-interfaces/blob/7872f1f78a44e6384529e22505e6ca0ba9b30a4d/src/DOMMatrix.js#L15-L18

I will update this once I implement that and have a working example. Pull requests welcome!

EDIT: the value `800` is the scene's perspective, I'm not sure if this is what the fourth value for the `DOMPoint` constructor should be when we intend to do something like this. Also, I'm not sure if I should use `preMultiplySelf` or `postMultiplySelf`. I'll find out once I get it at least working (values may be incorrect at first) and will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a polyfill to transfrom DOM coordinates. The GeometryUtils api is not available yet (@see https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/). I created a "simple" code in 2014 to transform coordinates, like localToGlobal, globalToLocal and localToLocal. Its not finished yet, but its working :) I think I will finish it in the coming months (05.07.2017), so if you still need a API to accomplish coordinate transformation give it a try: https://github.com/jsidea/jsidea [jsidea core library](https://github.com/jsidea/jsidea). Its **not stable yet** (pre alpha).
You can use it like that:

Create your transform instance:

```
var transformer = jsidea.geom.Transform.create(yourElement);
```

The box model you want to transform to (default:"border", will be replaced by ENUM's later on):

```
var toBoxModel = "border";
```

The box model where your input coordinates coming from (default:"border"):

```
var fromBoxModel = "border";
```

Transform your global coordinates (here {x:50, y:100, z: 0}) to local space. The resulting point has 4 components: x, y, z and w.

```
var local = transformer.globalToLocal(50, 100, 0, toBoxModel, fromBoxModel);
```

I have implemented some other functions like localToGlobal and localToLocal.
If you want to give a try, just download the release build and use the jsidea.min.js.

Download the first release here: [Download TypeScript code](https://github.com/jsidea/jsidea/releases/download/0.0.1/jsidea.core.pre.alpha.0.0.1.zip)

Feel free to change the code, I never put it under any license :)

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue and started trying to compute the matrix.
I started a library around it: https://github.com/ombr/referentiel

```
$('.referentiel').each ->
  ref = new Referentiel(this)
  $(this).on 'click', (e)->
    input = [e.pageX, e.pageY]
    p = ref.global_to_local(input)
    $pointer = $('.pointer', this)
    $pointer.css('left', p[0])
    $pointer.css('top', p[1])
```

What do you think ?

Answer (score -1):

### Works fine whether relative or absolute :) simple solution

```
var p = $( '.divName' );
var position = p.position();  
var left = (position.left  / 0.5);
var top =  (position.top  / 0.5);
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question that was asked.