# Find local coordinates of a screen coordinate on CSS3D element

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, coffeescript

I have a web page with an element which has a 3D perspective transformation.

I would like to find relative coordinates on that transformed object for a given screen coordinate. Or in other words, I want to do what is basically hit detection: find a relative coordinate on the element which corresponds to the mouse coordinates.

In Chrome/Safari it is trivial to find the perspective transform matrix for the element. I believe I need to do something like multiply the screen coordinates by the inverse of the perspective matrix, but the details are sadly lost on me.

I have created a Chrome/Safari/Webkit compatible jsFiddle with a partial implementation lacking the matrix math: http://jsfiddle.net/HT2VQ/

If the correct math were there, the blue doughnut drawn on the element would surround the red dot.

This is my coffeescript from the jsFiddle:

```
projectionMat = new WebKitCSSMatrix container.css('-webkit-transform')
window.onmousemove = (e) ->
    insideX = e.clientX - container.position().left
    insideY = e.clientY - container.position().top

    outsideCursor.css
        left: e.clientX
        top: e.clientY

    # Do something with projectionMat / projectionMat.inverse()
    # insideX = ??
    # insideY = ??

    insideCursor.css
        left: insideX
        top: insideY
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940214/show-me-a-javascript-implementation-of-webkitconvertpointfrompagetonode?noredirect=1#comment29402218_17940214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for Webkit without doing the matrix math by hand with [webkitConvertPointFromNodeToPage](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/DataManagement/Reference/DOMWindowAdditionsReference/DOMWindowAdditions/DOMWindowAdditions.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/DOMWindow/webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode):

```
point = webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode(container.get(0),
                                         new WebKitPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY))
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mlawrie/HT2VQ/5/