# getting mouse coordinates on a CSS 3D rotated canvas

Tags: javascript, matrix, canvas

I apologise that this question has been asked before

- [How to get a canvas relative mouse position of a CSS 3D transformed canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654650/how-to-get-a-canvas-relative-mouse-position-of-a-css-3d-transformed-canvas)
- [Best way to transform mouse coordinates to HTML5 Canvas's transformed context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835163/best-way-to-transform-mouse-coordinates-to-html5-canvass-transformed-context)
- [How to get the MouseEvent coordinates for an element that has CSS3 Transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773481/how-to-get-the-mouseevent-coordinates-for-an-element-that-has-css3-transform)
- [Real mouse position in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas)

but unfortunately I couldn't find an answer that I could get to work for me. Although the first-most on the list does appear to contain the solution, after a fair amount of time trying to adapt it to my needs I had to admit defeat.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is draw on a `<canvas>` element that has a CSS3 perspective rotation. To do that I think I need to project the mouse coordinates from the screen through the transform matrix, or rather it's inverse transform.

Interestingly (and mildly frustrating) enough, firefox's implementation of `event.layerX` and `event.layerY` does exactly what I'm looking for

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX

However being non-standard, it only works in Firefox. Chrome seems to treat it the same way as offsetX & offsetY.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// events

const pointermove = (event) => {
   const pointX = event.layerX;
   const pointY = event.layerY;
   context.fillRect(pointX - 1,pointY - 1,3,3);
}

canvas.addEventListener("pointermove",pointermove);
```

```css
body {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   perspective:600px;
   background-color:rgb(60,60,60);
}
div {
   transform-style:preserve-3d;
   transform:translateZ(-400px) rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-40deg);
}
canvas {
   background-color:rgb(230,230,230);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Alternatively, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130415/4911592) hinted at using `DOMMatrix` and `DOMPoint` which I would be happy to accept as a satisfactory solution that at least both Firefox and Chrome seem to support

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix/DOMMatrix

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint

However despite my best efforts I am unable to get it to work, I'm sorry to say. From what I understand, I need to apply the inverse of the canvas transform matrix to get the screen coordinates of the pointer position, and this is the closest I could get to

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// events

const pointermove = (event) => {
   const pointX = event.clientX * canvas.width / canvas.clientWidth;
   const pointY = event.clientY * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight;
   
   let point = new DOMPoint(pointX,pointY);
   const matrix = new DOMMatrix(window.getComputedStyle(canvas).transform);
   matrix.invertSelf();
   point = matrix.transformPoint(point);
   
   context.fillRect(pointX - 1,pointY - 1,3,3);
}

canvas.addEventListener("pointermove",pointermove);
```

```css
body {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   perspective:600px;
   background-color:rgb(60,60,60);
}
div {
   transform-style:preserve-3d;
   transform:translateZ(-400px) rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-40deg);
}
canvas {
   background-color:rgb(230,230,230);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

By tracing around the edges of the canvas, it looks like it is reproducing the transform inside the canvas, projecting the screen coordinates to local coordinates, but I may be wrong. I'm afraid my Math skills aren't up to the task of getting my head round matrices but I'm guessing I'm missing a multiplication somewhere...

would any of you kind, smart people out there know where I'm going wrong, or have any alternative (vanilla) solutions ?

thank you for your time

Edit : here is a fiddle using offsetX & offsetY that I couldn't figure out what was happening, hoping it might shed some light on what I got wrong in trying to apply the answer to the other questions

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// events

const pointermove = (event) => {
   const pointX = event.offsetX * canvas.width / canvas.clientWidth;
   const pointY = event.offsetY * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight;
   
   context.fillRect(pointX - 1,pointY - 1,3,3);
}

canvas.addEventListener("pointermove",pointermove);
```

```css
body {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   perspective:600px;
   background-color:rgb(60,60,60);
}
div {
   transform-style:preserve-3d;
   transform:translateZ(-400px) rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-40deg);
}
canvas {
   background-color:rgb(230,230,230);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

I also realised that haing gone round in a circle, I ended up copying almost verbatim the `DOMMatrix` post...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply @Kaiido, I hope my comment on your solution didn't seem offensive, it wasn't my intention. I've edited in a fiddle using `offsetX` & `offsetY` to illustrate how I didn't manage to get it to work - maybe it has something to do with compensating using a CSS transform on the canvas? but I think I tried that

Comment: No no it wasn't offensive at all no worries, I just really wondered what was your issue, I can now see that indeed in Firefox there is something odd with your snippet and I can't seem to understand what it is right now btw. Thanks for the edit, that's really what I was asking for and now your question clearly explains how it is not a duplicate of these linked Questions.

Comment: Sigh... I now realize [Firefox is broken](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1261645) and if it did seem to work in the other answer, it's only because of a fluck in the translateZ values... Sounds like you'll need browser spoofing and then use offsetXXX on Blink and layerXXX on Gecko...

Comment: ooh... there is a link to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373114/getting-the-touched-position-in-local-coordinates-of-a-transformed-element) and it's related [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gq1vLaxk/6/) in that thread though - I'll try and look at later and if I get anything working I'll post back here. Thank you so much for finding the source of the problem though @Kaiido, I feel a little bit less silly, and you're right that spoofing is an option.