# JQuery droppable doesn't detect drop events after applying rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am applying droppable to rotated element.

[Fiddle](https://codepen.io/rupesh-hurix/pen/dyVvjPX)

The droppable events are getting triggered on the area prior to rotation and it does not get triggered on actual rotated element.

HTML

```html
<div id="droppable">Drop here</div>
<div id="draggable">Drag me</div>
```

CSS

```css
#draggable {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #ccc;
}
#droppable {
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 80px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    transform-origin:center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Javascript

```js
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert( "dropped" );
  }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The issue is the Bounding Box cannot be read properly after the element has been transformed. The quick way (yet not great) to address this is to wrap the element and target the drop on the wrapper.

Comment: @Twisty I have tried that already, but it didnot work. I need the drop event to be captured exactly by the bounding box of the transformed element.

Comment: In that case, you will need to perform your own Collision detection via the `accept` option, when used as a function. See: https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept

Comment: You may also want to read the Top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773481/how-to-get-the-mouseevent-coordinates-for-an-element-that-has-css3-transform